# How do i activate the motherboards monitor slot?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, external-display

I have a 32 inch plugged into my HDMI, a 40in plugged into my normal monitor slot on my video card, but i want to plug in my 24in to my motherboard for misc. stuff.

What do I do?

Motherboard: Gigabyte MA785GM-US2H
Video Card:  ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series

Answer (score 0):

Since your motherboard supports ATi hybrid Crossfire you should be able to do this. You should go in the Advanced Feature Tab in your Motherboard BIOS and enable the SurroundView